# Arrow marker on google maps API for Android

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I need to develop an application for Android that uses the Google Maps API.
I the need to use a marker that show me my position and rotation exactly like the one shown in the figure (Link: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Sy61Gjk7aKA/Tw2Lo553AiI/AAAAAAAAAVI/oJ7tiGb-lts/s1600/2.jpg).
Is it possible to realize?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an answer to a similar question: [Google Map Heading Marker or Indicator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18858720/google-map-heading-marker-or-indicator/20173310#20173310)

I haven't tried it in 3D, but there's no reason why it shouldn't work.